# Почему не работает (не обновляется ListView из BroadcastReceiver)?

Tags: android, list, broadcast-receiver, android-broadcastreceiver

имею такой код:

```
public class AddNewRequestActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lvMain;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    final ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
    names.add("Ivan");
    names.add("Anton");
    lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRequests);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddNewRequestActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               names.clear();
                    names.add("Ivan");
                    names.add("Anton");
                    names.add("Sasha");
                    names.add("Viktor");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(br, intFilt);
    }
}
```

но после того как срабатывает onReceive в Listview отображаются только "Ivan", "Anton", т.е. ListView не обновляется. что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте не создавать новый массив, а изменить тип данный, передающихся в адаптер на ArrayList и в ресивере, не трогая адаптер, очитстить список в активити и добавить в него новые элементы. После чего уведомить адаптер об этом.

Пользоваться массивами вообще в ListView не стоит - используйте ArrayList

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40981/discussion-on-answer-by-------listview--b).